# MySQL data count in 10 minute intervals

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, time, group-by

I have a table that records the datetime a student leaves along with their details.

What I want to do is count how many students leave between two set times listing all the times at 10 minute intervals.

This script will count the number of students who leave but only if students leave in the 10 minute interval being counted, it just skips any 10 minutes that have no students leaving.

I need it to return all the time intervals between the datetimes given with 0 if no students leave in that time interval so that no time is missed.

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        CEILING(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_left`) / 600
        ) * 600
    ) AS timeslice,
    COUNT(*) AS mycount
FROM
    tbl_student_log
WHERE
    `time_left` >= '2016-02-01 12:00:00'
AND `time_left` < '2016-02-01 17:00:00'
GROUP BY
    timeslice
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78c5c/1/0)

Test Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_student_log` (
`id`  int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`student_id`  int(5) NOT NULL ,
`time_left`  datetime NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_student_log` VALUES (1, 2, '2016-02-01 12:06:24');
INSERT INTO `tbl_student_log` VALUES (2, 4, '2016-02-01 12:13:42');
INSERT INTO `tbl_student_log` VALUES (3, 5, '2016-02-01 12:14:01');
INSERT INTO `tbl_student_log` VALUES (4, 8, '2016-02-01 14:07:25');
```

SQL

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        CEILING(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_left`) / 600
        ) * 600
    ) AS timeslice,
    COUNT(*) AS mycount
FROM
    tbl_student_log
WHERE
    `time_left` >= '2016-02-01 12:00:00'
AND `time_left` < '2016-02-01 17:00:00'
GROUP BY
    timeslice
```

Output from above data is:

```
12:10 = 1  
12:20 = 2  
14:10 = 1
```

Actual output I need is:

```
12:00 = 0  
12:10 = 1  
12:20 = 2  
12:30 = 0  
12:40 = 0  
...  
14:10 = 1  
...  
17:00 = 0
```

With all times between dates returning a value

Comment: Here's a writeup on this topic. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: Thanks @OllieJones for the link, reading over this and doing some more research I don't think this is an easy query using pure MySQL. I have managed to achieve what I was trying to do using PHP to create an array of the times then updating array with result from Query.

Comment: can you pls explain more. Can you show me your output ?

Comment: @Monty Based on the above sample data and SQL Fiddle the output is 12:10 = 1, 12:20 = 2 and 14:10 = 1. The actual output needed was 12:00 = 0, 12:10 = 1, 12:20 = 2, 12:30 = 0, 12:40 = 0 etc.. right up to 17:00 = 0

Comment: see my answer @LeeElvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ohh... Man, your question was **difficult**, After spending **5 hours** on
>   this query. I **found solution** using **query**.

**Steps :**

`1.) you have to create procedure.` [Click here](https://github.com/gabfl/mysql_generate_series)

```
2.) Download it and import "generate_series.sql" in your table.
3.) You have to run two queries :
    3.1) 1st you have to call procedure.
    3.2) 2nd you have to write another query.
```

After importing **generate_series.sql** in your table, you have to write query like this :

```
CALL generate_series_date_minute('2016-02-01 11:50', '2016-02-01 17:00:00', 10);

SELECT (s.series + interval 10 MINUTE) AS timeslice, count(t.time_left) AS mycount
FROM series_tmp AS s LEFT JOIN tbl_student_log AS t
ON true
AND t.time_left > s.series
AND t.time_left <= (s.series + interval 10 MINUTE)
GROUP BY s.series limit 31
```

**Note :** if you want to change interval from 10 to 15 or 20, or any then you have to change in your query and procedure, You also have to write **from** and **to** date in procedure. You can even change procedure (See [documentation](https://github.com/gabfl/mysql_generate_series))

**Example :** generate_series_date_minute(from, to, interval);

**OUTPUT :**

```
timeslice                   mycount
2016-02-01 12:00:00           0
2016-02-01 12:10:00           1
2016-02-01 12:20:00           2
2016-02-01 12:30:00           0
2016-02-01 12:40:00           0
2016-02-01 12:50:00           0
2016-02-01 13:00:00           0
2016-02-01 13:10:00           0
2016-02-01 13:20:00           0
2016-02-01 13:30:00           0
2016-02-01 13:40:00           0
2016-02-01 13:50:00           0
2016-02-01 14:00:00           0
2016-02-01 14:10:00           1
2016-02-01 14:20:00           0
2016-02-01 14:30:00           0 
2016-02-01 14:40:00           0
2016-02-01 14:50:00           0
2016-02-01 15:00:00           0
2016-02-01 15:10:00           0
2016-02-01 15:20:00           0
2016-02-01 15:30:00           0
2016-02-01 15:40:00           0
2016-02-01 15:50:00           0
2016-02-01 16:00:00           0
2016-02-01 16:10:00           0
2016-02-01 16:20:00           0
2016-02-01 16:30:00           0
2016-02-01 16:40:00           0
2016-02-01 16:50:00           0
2016-02-01 17:00:00           0
```

Comment: Well done on sharing a pure MySQL based solution and for giving a clear answer, I've changed yours to the correct answer as my original question was asking for a pure MySQL answer and mine, while correct, included PHP. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve my query using PHP as well as MySQL as I haven't been able to find a pure MySQL solution.

First I setup an array of the times using the time interval as the key and setting a default value to 0

```
$times       = array();
$start_time  = "2016-02-01 12:00:00";
$end_time    = "2016-02-01 17:00:00";
$interval    = "+10 minutes";

$current = $start_time;
while( strtotime($current) <= strtotime($end_time) )
{
    $times[date('H:i', strtotime($current))] = 0;
    $current = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($interval, strtotime($current)));
}
```

Then using the result from my query I updated the array with the values to the fields that were not 0

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $times[date('H:i', strtotime($row['timeslice']))] = $row['mycount'];
}
```

Not sure if anyone can come up with a pure MySQL solution.